# CoreData sort using two fields

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I am trying to sort CoreData entity by two fields schedule_order and activity_order. I want to sort by schedule_order then keep it sorted by that and sort by activity_order while keeping the schedule_order in tact.

I have tried this:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "schedule_order", ascending: true)
let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "activity_order", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor,sortDescriptor1]
```

Do I need to do this a different way? I have one case where it isn't sorting it correctly. The one that should be appearing first keeps up ending up at the end.

Comment: That looks correct. Can you provide a (minimal) example where it does not produce the expected result? What *types* have the attributes?

Comment: Use one of them! If you have a section header in your project? And then you can use both sortDescriptors. First sortDescriptors for the section header and the second sortDescriptors for your cells order